# Is agiletoolkit (atk) framework dead?

Tags: atk4

I want to choose `ATK` (http://agiletoolkit.org) as my framework for easily build the admin part, I have 2 questions.

1. In their site, I see that the last blog post was a year a go.
   Is this project continuing?
2. Should I use this framework in the site AND the admin? I am a bit confused about using it in the site side? Or maybe I should use another framework (which will create an overhead)..

**Edit**
I am a developer that is coming from JAVA and .net mostly.
I am a freak of service reuse because I have an experience on a large scale projects.
I see that ATK4 is not a classic REST based.

Lets examine this situation if I may:
Just as an example, I have a registration form that has a very complex logic in pre-insert and post-insert.
So it means that I need to create a REST api for registration (with all the complex pre-post logic).
BUT! the crud operation will not be arware for this complex logic in it, so I am creating some sort of a pit-fall when I cant re-use CRUD operation from the site and vice versa.
I am use to create single service that is suitable with admin CRUD and site operation, this way you wont have duplicate invocations, and each operation is aware to the permissions you have.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Site is now in the process of complete rewrite. Their blog never was active enough.

BUT this project is very alive and very active. For all news you should check these resources:

- GitHub repository - https://github.com/atk4/atk4. As you can see there are new commits almost every day.
- Google groups for discusions - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/agile-toolkit-devel Same story - new posts every day.
- IRC - #atk4 at freenode
- Stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atk4
- YouTube - video tutorials
- some more resources for addons etc.

You can use ATK4 for whatever type of site you want. I guess it better suits for admin (backoffice) side, but can be used equally well in frontend too. It's just - learning curve can sometimes be not so short. On the other hand - when you get used to ATK4 style of coding, then it definitely sucks you in :))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edit my question, can you please have a look at the EDIT section? thanks

Comment: I guess I'll not be the pest person to answer your Edit part. I hope Romans (developer of ATK) will have time to answer this. At least I'll let him know when I next time see him online in IRC or somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Update on Agile Toolkit as of 2017:

In order to keep the best parts of ATK4 framework alive, I have started 2 open-source projects following best practices:

- https://github.com/atk4/data - Agile Data - Refactor for models
- https://github.com/atk4/ui - Agile UI - Refactor for UI

Additional resources (forum, blog, etc) can be found at http://agiletookit.org/.